# Which is the current decimal separator?

Tags: shell, posix, locale, floating-point

Say I have a POSIX shell script that

1. needs to run on different systems/environments  that I do not control, and
2. needs to remove the decimal separator from a string that is emitted by a program that respects the locale settings.

How can I detect the decimal separator in the most general way?

Comment: What sort of script ? Where is it running ? Please update your question, so that it can be answered.

Comment: @XTian A generic shell script, that's running on a Unix/Linux system. ֎    I deliberately posed the question in the most general way because I'm interested in the most general answer, as I specified in the last line of my question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas A POSIX script! Honest, I forgot that i used to use `tcsh` in ..., oh my, you definitely can say that I'm OLD!!!

Comment: Can't you run the string-emitted program under a `LC_ALL=C` environment?

Comment: @Ángel Oh yes, of course I could...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ask [`locale`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/locale.html):

```
locale decimal_point
```

This will output the decimal point using the current locale settings.

If you need the thousands separator:

```
locale thousands_sep
```

You can view all the numeric keywords by requesting [the `LC_NUMERIC` category](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07):

```
locale -k LC_NUMERIC
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the number directly formatted using the current locale's decimal/thousands separators?

Comment: @muru `printf "%'f"` would do it, for `printf` implementations which support `%f`.

Comment: @muru The only _builtin_ that I know of, that can output a decimal separator, is `printf` and some shell (e.g., `dash`) do not support internationalized output.  In another answer Stéphane Chazelas explained, in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541342/which-is-the-current-decimal-separator#comment1003598_541355), that it's not required by POSIX

Answer (score 6):

If that's a `zsh` shell script, you can use the `$langinfo` special associative array in the `zsh/langinfo` module:

```
zmodload zsh/langinfo
radix=$langinfo[RADIXCHAR]
```

(that maps to the standard `nl_langinfo(RADIXCHAR)`, see `man nl_langinfo` on your system for details; `$langinfo[THOUSEP]` for the thousand separator).

In a `bash` script (would also work in `zsh`), you should be able to get it without forking a separate process using the `printf` builtin:

```
printf -v radix %.1f 1 && radix=${radix:1:1}
```

To convert a number from the user's locale format to the C locale format, with the ksh93 shell, you could do it like:

```
$ locale title
German locale for Germany
$ x=1.123.456,78 ksh -c 'typeset -F x="$x"; LC_ALL=C; printf "%.23g\n" "$x"'
1123456.78
```

Comment: Most generic, could it be? `tmp=$(printf %.1f 0);tmp=${tmp#0};radix=${tmp%0}`

Comment: @gboffi, that  would work in some internationalized `printf` implementations that support `%f`, but not all. `%f` support is not mandated by POSIX. The `printf` of `dash` for instance always uses `.`

Comment: re `dash` not internationalized... I've just found that... so the most general solution is resorting to `locale decimal_point`, isn't it?

Comment: @gboffi, probably. GNU `awk` can also interpret numbers in the current locale with when in POSIX mode (doesn't handle the thousand separator though).